# Не работает добавление данных в таблицу на php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Когда учитель регистрируется на сайте его ФИО и другие данные вносятся в БД, код для регистрации работает данные добавляются в таблицу, но когда точно такой же код, разумеется изменив название таблицы и соответствующих полей в таблице, я пишу для регистрации ученика, данные не добавляются, не понимаю в чем ошибка, прикрепляю код регистрации учителя и ученика

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$patronymic = $_POST['patronymic'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$password = md5($password."ghdfj");

$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "epilog");
$mysql->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `teachers` (`name`, `surname`, `patronymic`, `email`, `password`) 
VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$patronymic', '$email', '$password')");


header('Location: index.php');

$mysql->close();
?>
```

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$patronymic = $_POST['patronymic'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$class_numb = $_POST['class_numb'];
$class_letter = $_POST['class_letter'];

$password = md5($password."ghdfj");

$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "epilog");
$mysql->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `students` (`name`, `surname`, `patronymic`, `email`, `password`, `class_numb`, `class_letter`) 
VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$patronymic', '$email', '$password', '$class_numb', '$class_letter')");


$mysql->close();
?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Ну ошибку-то какую-то выдает?